# Подобрать регулярное выражение python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

У меня есть список cd команд. Мне нужно выбрать только правильные из них использую re python.
Пример:

```
echo %cd% #False
cd C:\\User\\data 1\\data
cd C:\\User lldo #False
cd ../directory #True
cd C:\\ #True
text cd C:\\ #False
....
```

Помогите пожалуйста подогнать моё регулярное выражение под эту задачу?

Моё регулярное выражение

```py
(.*)(cd \w*)(.*)
```

**UPD**
Там где есть комментарий #True, команда правильная. Там где #False, неправильная. В винде как и в остальных системах есть команда cd. cd принимает один аргумент - путь. Если мы введём такую text cd C: или такую cd C: text команду, то мы получим ошибку. Мне нужно проверить, является ли строка валидной командой cd.

Спасибо

Comment: какие команды из приведенного примера - правильные? по какому принципу их отбирать?

Comment: @strawdog, Там где есть комментарий #True, команда правильная. Там где #False, неправильная. В винде как и в остальных системах есть команда cd. cd принимает один аргумент - путь. Если мы введём такую text cd C: или такую cd C: text команду, то мы получим ошибку. Мне нужно проверить, является ли строка валидной командой cd.

Comment: а откуда появляются комментарии True? они как-то где-то задаются? Если да, то не проще ли проверять наличие комментария True, зачем тогда регулярки?

Comment: @Ymka Т.е. задача "Выполнится ли эта `cd` команда без ошибок"?

Comment: @strawdog Эти комментарии я написал для примера

Comment: @Ymka Есть ли какие-то ограничения на ввод? Могут быть опции команды?

Comment: Т.е. задача "Выполнится ли эта cd команда без ошибок"? Нет

Comment: Тогда исправьте свой вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, по какому принципу выбирать правильные команды. у вас уже простыня комментариев с уточнениями, а толку 0. Если вам просто нужно отобрать команды, где перед cd нет ничего другого, то так и напишите.

Comment: Есть ли какие-то ограничения на ввод? Нет. Могут быть опции команды? Нет

Comment: `^cd\s+(?:"[^"]*"|\.{2}/\S*|[A-Z]:\\\\\S*)$` - https://regex101.com/r/gIw8JC/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, спасибо, но на этом примере ваше регулярное выражение не работает.                                     cd C:\\User\\data 1\\data

Comment: А это неверная строка. И не должно работать.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Я с вами полностью согласен, но путь C:\\User\\data 1\\data в windows тоже существует. И как быть? Просто игнорировать пути такого типа?

Comment: Когда такой путь существует, он должен быть в каычках. Видите моё регулярное выражение? Оно только такие и находит (`"[^"]*"`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, какая задача у ТСа. Первое, что приходит на ум при таком расплывчатом описании:

```py
import shlex  # Модуль для лексического анализа простого синтаксиса, подобного unix shell


cmds = (  # Команды для проверки
    r'echo %cd%', #False
    r'cd C:\\User lldo', #False
    r'cd ../directory', #True
    r'cd C:\\', #True
    r'text cd C:\\' #False
)

for cmd in cmds:
    tokens = shlex.split(cmd)  # Разбиваем команду на unix-токены
    
    # Выводим команду и результат проверки на то, что эта команда состоит только из двух токенов и первый токен cd
    print(f'{cmd} #{len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0] == "cd"}')
```

Comment: shlex.split(r'cd C:\\Users\\User\\data 1\\data') выдаёт
['cd', 'C:\\Users\\User\\data', '1\\data']. Следовательно, наша проверка не пройдёт.
len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0] == "cd" это выражение будет равно False

Comment: Но всё равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: Во-первых, в классическом варианте эта строка не является "правильной", это уже какие-то виндовые извраты, что она съедается. Во-вторых, по Вашей логике `r'cd C:\\User lldo'` тоже должно быть `True`, Вы же написали `False` для неё. Вы в этом топике уже второй раз противоречите сами себе.

Comment: А как же быть? Что делать с такими путями: C:\\Users\\data\\data 1\\

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, Согласен с Nikto

Comment: cd "C:\\path with spaces" работает